# How to use the rerenderEvents() method on a pre-rendered Calendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

UPDATED 3-26-2019

I am trying to give users the ability to add events to the Calendar and for those events to appear upon input. I am using a React.js front end and can get the events to render in a new calendar but it does not delete the old one (I just end up with **10+** calenders that render on top of each other).

I've tried using the `.destroy()` method and then re-rendering the calendar but the method doesn't seem to be available/functioning so I figured I would try `rerenderEvents()` and keep the same calendar object but that function doesn't seem to be accessible either. Would love some assistance in solving this from anyone who is familiar with **FullCalendar v.4**

Once the user inputs the data it's collected into a data object and append it into the state but if I just mirror the above, it renders a whole new calendar on top of the old one.

It's like I cannot get the Calendar object once rendered to make those method calls, but am having trouble capturing it in a separate function. All the Docs say is call the `.destroy()` or call the `.rerenderEvents()` and not what to call them on.

```
//This successfully Renders
    componentOnMount() {
                 var calendarNew = document.getElementById('calendar');



            let newCalendar = new Calendar(calendarNew, {
                plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin ],
                events: this.state.events
            });


            console.log(newCalendar)

            await this.setState({ calendarObj: newCalendar })

            // let myNewEvents = newCalendar.getEvents()
            // console.log(myNewEvents)
            // let stateEvents = this.state.calendarObj.getEvents()
            // console.log(stateEvents)

            this.state.calendarObj.render();


    }
```

I've tried the following to mitigate the double render...

```
    async handleNewEvent() {
    // code that creates an object and sets the state to the new event array//
        var newEventArr = existingEvents.concat(newEvent)
        console.log(newEventArr)

        await this.setState({ events: newEventArr })
        await this.setState({ currentIndex: (this.state.currentIndex + 1) })
        this.props.change(this.state.events, this.state.currentIndex)

        //Contains the new event array in the console
        console.log(this.state.events)

       this.state.calendarObj.rerenderEvents();
    }
```

But this does nothing. I cannot even render() from the handleNewEvent() as it appears as if the state is unable to hold functions in it and I cannot find a way to pass the function from the ComponentDidMount() to the handleNewEvent(). Im at a loss...

Comment: Can you add your code to codesandbox.

Comment: you should be calling methods against the `calendar` object, not `calendarEl` - that just represents the HTML element into which the calendar is inserted, it does not contain any of the functionality. If you want to be able to call methods of `calendar` from different places in your app, then ensure that the `calendar` variable has sufficient scope (e.g. it's global or has very high-level scope in some other way) so that it's accessible.

Comment: So I managed to render the Calender after storing it in the state of the component but now the rerenderEvents() does nothing.